# Does Islam teach the circumcision of the breath?

Tags: zoroastrianism

**In Zoroastrianism the saying goes 'Good Thoughts, Good Words, Good Deeds'**
The circumcision of breath is when "sayings about error" are cut out of ones dialect.

**Using a car with a flat tire as an example:**

- The 'Bad Words' would be 'The car has a flat tire.'
- The 'Good Words' would be 'The tire is going to be fixed.'

How does this compare to Islam? Is evil(meaning error) speech cut out from the dialect? Or again, 'Is speaking about error cut out from ones dialect?'

Or do they continue to point out:

"This is wrong, this is wrong, and this is broke", like King Thornbush who was cut down and thrown into the crematory.

Comment: Can you please reword your question, its pretty hard to understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: @TashannaChamma If I could understand your difficulty then it would be possible. Have you never met a person who points out error? Have you never met a person who said "You did this wrong"? How did you feel when told this? Do you love others when you make them feel this way?

Comment: yes i understand what you mean. To be honest, my personal opinion is that if for example i saw my muslim brother or sister doing something wrong, it is my duty as a muslim to let them know. However i will tell them privately, not to embarass them, and i will InShaAllah cover their bad deed as much as i can because he who covers for his brother in this dunya, Allah SWT will cover for him on yom lkiyama

Comment: @TashannaChamma Yes, this is the difference. Say your brother was to leave a room when the woman entered and he did not. The evil spirit/breath says, "You did not leave the room when you where supposed to". The holy spirit/breath says, "When the woman enters the room, he is going to be leaving when he is supposed to." Saying this to Allah is enough to accomplish the task. Some sayings do not need to go to the man. Allah is actually that strong.

Comment: i didnt quite understand that, can you give another example please?

Comment: @TashannaChamma The difference in that one saying shows error within functionality, and the other prophecies the result of the positive thought. The spirit of error, "The air conditioner is broke.", "This is a bad paint job.", "My foot hurts.". The holy spirit, "The air conditioner is going to be working.", "This paint job is going to be awesome when it is done.", "My foot will be better."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about "Half of the glass is empty" and "half of the glass is full" concept.

Well, Qur'an, lays importance (caution) on the usage of words for example like [this](http://quran.com/2/199-202). In other words, we need to lay emphasis on what we vow, and what we say about God almighty and we need to be cautious that we don't say something which could be considered Polytheism.

Other than that, as far as I know, there are no specific verses of Qur'an which compel us to talk in an optimistic fashion. But, it explicitly suggests us to do so by asking us to be patient. **Being patient in worse conditions might be considered as encouraging 'Optimism'**.

May the creator guide us all.